# Renew my ip address (dhclient not found)

Tags: debian, networking

I recently got a new cable modem and my internet connection is no longer working. I suspect I need to renew my IP address. How can I renew my address?

The command `ifconfig` returns:

```
bash: ifconfig: command not found
```

The command `dhclient` returns:

```
bash: dhclient: command not found
```

I am using Debian 7 (Wheezy).

**------- ANSWER**

It appears the problem was that I was trying to mess with the network using my *user account*, which I did not realize was not a good idea. I must have been logged in as root when I did it before. The easy solution is:

```
sudo /sbin/dhclient eth0
```

This command reset my connection and my Debian system has network connectivity again. The key thing, as the answer below noted, is that user accounts do not normally have /sbin in the path, so you have to give the explicit path to dhclient if you using it via a user account.

Comment: Being in user mode is not a typo and can definitely be reproduced. This is a common type of error that could (and does) affect many people. This is a useful question.

Comment: I can't see why this wouldn't be on topic. The answer is simple `/sbin` isn't in the path. 6,125 people came here and the answer is well upvoted. Clearly it's useful. And, I can reproduce it.

Comment: The most probable reasons are: 1) `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` are not in your `PATH`, check it with an `echo "$PATH"` command 2) `ifconfig` is obsolete, today we use `ip` 2) `dhclient` is not installed on all systems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's installed, `dhclient` would be in `/sbin`, which normally is not in your user path.  If you do

```
sudo su -
```

then your path would have that directory:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

However, `ifconfig` also lives in that directory, so it seems likely you do not have that installed.  The package (if you have a CD for installing...) is [`isc-dhcp-client`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=isc-dhcp-client)

Answer (score 2):

Some systems that are lacking `dhclient` still have the basic `busybox` implementation of `dhcp` client:

```
udhcpc
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning `udhcpc`  I wasn't able to find single reference for it .